# How to make a readable comparison of lists in mock.assert_called_with?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, assertion

How do I get a readable result when calling assert_called_with(param) if param is a list? To make it clear which elements of the list are different.

**Example:**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
    
def func1(param):
    pass

def test1():

    with patch('test1.func1') as mock1:
        func1(['a', 'b'])
        mock1.assert_called_with(['f', 'b'])

pytest test1.py
```

*The output is unreadable.* With a large list, it will be difficult to see the differences with your eyes:

```
Expected: func1(['f', 'b'])
Actual: func1(['a', 'b'])
```

**1. Readable result example:**

```
def test_1():
    assert ['a', 'b'] == ['f', 'b']

pytest test1.py
```

output:

```
At index 0 diff: 'a' != 'f'
```

**2. Readable result example:**

```
from unittest import TestCase

TestCase().assertListEqual(['a', 'b'], ['f', 'b'])
```

output:

```
   First differing element 0:
    'a'
    'f'
```